# CiviCase Will Not Save Settings for Activities

Tags: civicase

I am using CiviCRM 4.5.5 on Drupal 7.

When I go to the settings page for my Case configuration (Administer -> CiviCase ->Case Types) I can add activities to the list of activities and appears to save.  No error message is being raised.  However if you edit the Case type again you will that none of your changes are there.

I  will note that this instance of CiviCRM and CiviCase have been upgraded since somewhere in Civi 3.x.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things to look out for.

If you are creating a new case type, we had to delete the default role that is automatically assigned (case coordinator I believe), save and then re-add the role before it would save.

If you are working form the older xml files to configure cases, I'm not sure that the case ui will work with those.  You may have to edit those files manually.

Comment: Thanks!Does anyone know if wecan just ditch the XML files?

Comment: I have now moved the XML files and I still cannot save . I am wondering if I need to just delete the case and start over again....thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new test case from scratch using only the UI?

Comment: I had not, when I try and create a test case I get  "Sorry an error occurred and your information was not saved" Hmmm.... I will make a copy of the site and see what happens if delete the old one and create a new one.

Comment: I occasionally got that error only to go back and see that the case type was created.  If it was, try deleting the default role, save and then add a default role.

Comment: The only thing I came up with to get this to work was to delete all of the cases and then delete the case.  It was not what we wanted to do but it worked.